# PyQt5 save QByteArray to json format

Tags: python, json, pyqt, pyqt5, qbytearray

This one is a pickle. I'm trying to save my window/other elements to json format so that I can have multiple data stored in 1 place for my window/etc

I know that QByteArray has these functions:
std::string QByteArray::toStdString() const
and
QByteArray QByteArray::fromStdString(const std::string &str)

Which should allow me to do it but so far I can't get it to work in Python. 
Some info about I found here (C) >
[Correct way to losslessly convert to and from std::string and QByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767760/correct-way-to-losslessly-convert-to-and-from-stdstring-and-qbytearray)

I tried doing something like this:

```
print(self.saveGeometry())
bar = self.saveGeometry()
print(bytes(str(bar).encode()))
```

to convert QByteArray to bytearray that then I could save as string but I'm getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Can any1 suggest how can I use either the native QT5 5.4+ function to save QByteArray to QByteArray.toStdString to json then load json > to QByteArray.fromStdString > to geometry or other method ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON cannot serialize `bytes/bytearray` objects, so you need to convert them to unicode objects instead. That means it's necessary to somehow "decode" the raw bytes data contained in the `QByteArray`. One way to do this is to convert the bytes to some ascii-compatible format first, so as to avoid any unicode errors:

```
>>> g = widget.saveGeometry()
>>> d = json.dumps(bytes(g.toHex()).decode('ascii'))
>>> x = QByteArray.fromHex(bytes(json.loads(d), 'ascii'))
>>> x == g
True
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I got as far as toHex(), but could not get it to work, thank you so much for that answer!