# How to get datas send by Protobuf with a QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I'm new on protobuf and `QTcpServer/Socket` and I want to read my `.proto` data send by my client, but when i'm reading the data, the `QString` done is empty

For now, I just want to send a message that say "hello" when my client is connected. The `QByteArray` returning by `QTcpSocket::readAll` is NOT empty, but the `QString` created with the bytes is empty.

Here is my `.proto` ultra basic one :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;
message Message
{
    string content = 2;
}
```

write functions :

```cpp
// When i'm connecting to the server i create a PlayerManager and i call this function with message = "hello"
void Server::sendMessageToPlayer(const PlayerManager& playerManager, const QString& message)
{
    auto messageProto = new protobuf::Message;
    messageProto->set_content(message.toStdString());

    playerManager.socketManager()->sendData(*messageProto);
}

// I serialize the protobuf
template <typename protobufType>
void sendData(const protobufType& protobuf)
{
    std::string dataToSend;
    if (!protobuf.SerializeToString(&dataToSend))
    {
        // This never pass -> the protobuf is well serialize 
        qDebug() << "The protobuf send cannot be serialized, please, make sure that you used protobufs correctly";
    }

    // Before i write it
    write(dataToSend);
}

void SocketManager::write(const std::string& data)
{
    // I tried this but it's not working either
    // QTextCodec* codec     = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251");
    // QString     codecData = codec->toUnicode(data.c_str());

    QByteArray  block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);

    out << data.c_str();
    _tcpSocket->write(block);
    qDebug() << block;
}
```

read functions :

```cpp
void SocketManager::read()
{
    QByteArray bytes = _tcpSocket->readAll();
    qDebug() << bytes;

    // Doesn't work either
    // QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251");
    // QString     data  = codec->toUnicode(bytes);
    QString     data(bytes);
    qDebug() << data;

    emitMessageType(data.toStdString());
}

void SocketManager::emitMessageType(const std::string& data)
{
    // Protobufs can parse an empty string (and so, emit signal), to avoid that, the function will tell you if data
    // are empty, then return
    if (data.empty())
    {
        qDebug() << "Datas are empty";
        return;
    }

    protobuf::Message message;
    if (message.ParseFromString(data))
    {
        emit messageProtoReceived(message);
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "The data send cannot be translate, please, make sure that you used protobufs correctly";
}
```

So, I would like that my client receive "hello" when he is connected but my debug are :

Server side :

```
"\x00\x00\x00\b\x12\x05hello\x00"
```

Client side

```
"\x00\x00\x00\b\x12\x05hello\x00"
""
Datas are empty
```

When I use `QTextCodec` (commented lines of the code) the debug are :

Server side :

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x12\x00\x05\x00h\x00""e\x00l\x00l\x00o"
```

Client side

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x12\x00\x05\x00h\x00""e\x00l\x00l\x00o"
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000E\u0000\u0012\u0000\u0005\u0000h\u0000e\u0000l\u0000l\u0000o"
The data send cannot be translate, please, make sure that you used protobufs correctly
```

So the `QByteArea` is parse, but protobuf don't succeed to parse the given string.

Thanks for reading, I hope youc ould help me

Comment: `out << data.c_str()` inside write function might discard at first `\0`. Try converting to `QByteArray` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767760/correct-way-to-losslessly-convert-to-and-from-stdstring-and-qbytearray to ensure whole string is sent via socket.

Comment: `QByteArray  block(data.c_str(), data.length());`
`QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);`
`out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);`
`_tcpSocket->write(block);`

This is working ty ! Could you answer, I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out << data.c_str()` inside `SocketManager::write` might discard at first `\0`. Try converting to `QByteArray` as described at [Correct way to losslessly convert to and from std::string and QByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767760/correct-way-to-losslessly-convert-to-and-from-stdstring-and-qbytearray) to ensure the whole string is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the case but the documentation says that the default constructor of a `QString` that takes a `QByteArray`:

> The given byte array is converted to Unicode using fromUtf8(). Stops copying at the first 0 character, otherwise copies the entire byte array.

So probably, you are having some troubles whit the conversion.

As alternative, you can try [`ParseFromArray`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite) method, instead of converting a `QByteArray` into a `std::string`.

```
const auto byteArray = _tcpSocket->readAll();
protobuf::Message message;
if (!message.ParseFromArray(byteArray.data(), byteArray.size())) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to parse person.pb.";
}
```

Comment: This is working, but only when i do what @Zaiborg told me to do. And it's work also with ParseFromString :). Thanks anyway !
But I have another problem and you seems to know protobuf. To be clearer on my code, I omit to say that I try to parse different kind of `.proto` in my `emitMessageType` function. The first to be parse is protobuf::Player and it's asking an int AND a string. But protobuf::Player success the parse with a string serialize by a protobuf::Message and it's anoying

Comment: sorry @Ephesiel, but I don't get your problem, maybe you could provide an update in your question with a small example of the protobuf model or the code itself.

Comment: Sorry it's difficult to explain in a little comment, here is a link to an other question that i ask -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287462/why-my-protobuf-class-can-parse-a-string-serialized-by-an-other-protobuf-class)