# Why my Protobuf class can parse a string serialized by an other Protobuf class

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I tried to know what package I got in my tcp socket, so I use protobuf.
But when I `SerializeToString` my first protobuf class, the `ParseFromString` method of an other protobuf class returns true.

The two classes are differents

Here are my `.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;
message Message
{
    string content = 1;
}
message Player
{
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Here is my c++ code

```cpp
auto messageProto = new protobuf::Message;
messageProto->set_content("Hello");

std::string data;
messageProto->SerializeToString(&data);

protobuf::Player player;
if (player.ParseFromString(data))
{
    qDebug() << "parse player";
}

protobuf::Message message2;
if (message2.ParseFromString(data))
{
    qDebug() << "parse message";
}
```

Output :

```
parse player
parse message
```

Why ?

Comment: Deserializing with the wrong type is undefined behaviour. It might work "fine". It might throw.

Comment: But how can I know what type will be the good one ? This is an example but in my program, I only get a string and I want to know from what type it came !!

Comment: @Ephesiel You can't know from just looking at the serialized string.  You must store the message type separately.

Comment: @Miles Budnek okay, I implement something like that, each time that I send a message, I send another message before called Header which contain the message type. Then, according to the type, I will parse a different protobuf class. So now i have an other problem, when I write two messages, both are read in the same time in me QTcpSocket, but this is an other problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: In this scenario, IMO you should use a single outer message type with a "oneof" inner message. Then the answer is always "the single outer type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommended solution to the problem of multiple different payloads:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;
message RenameMe // the outer payload wrapper
{
  oneof payload
  {
    Foo foo = 1;
    Bar bar = 2;
  }
}
message Foo // one type of content
{
    string content = 1;
}
message Bar // another type of content
{
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Now you can just deserialize everything as a `RenameMe` (naming is hard!) and check the `payload` discriminated union enum to see how you should interpret the data. Then just access `foo` or `bar` respectively.

This approach is clear, obvious, and readily and effectively extensible into additional message types. The testing can be implemented with `switch` in many programming languages. This style also works well with polymorphism in some environments - for example, in C# with protobuf-net that could be serialized/deserialized with:

```cs
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Foo)), ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Bar))]
abstract class RenameMe {}

[ProtoContract]
class Foo : RenameMe {
  [ProtoMember(1)] public string Content {get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
class Bar : RenameMe {
  [ProtoMember(1)] public int Id {get;set;}
  [ProtoMember(2)] public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I didn't know how to answer you, but i needed to write some code, so I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : So, now, is it the best approach ?

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Header
{
    oneof payload
    {
        Message message = 1;
        Player player = 2;
    }
}
message Message
{
    string content = 1;
}
message Player
{
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

When I write :

```cpp
void SocketManager::sendData(Player& player)
{
    Header header;
    header.set_allocated_player(&player);
    write(header);
}

void SocketManager::sendData(Message& message)
{
    Header header;
    header.set_allocated_message(&message);
    write(header);
}

// etc... for each kind of message
```

When I read :

```cpp
void read(const std::string& data)
{
    protobuf::Header header;
    header.ParseFromString(data);

    switch (header.payload_case())
    {
    case protobuf::Header::kMessage:
        emit messageProtoReceived(header.message());
        break;
    case protobuf::Header::kPlayer:
        emit playerProtoReceived(header.player());
        break;
    case protobuf::Header::PAYLOAD_NOT_SET:
        qDebug() << "Error, the payload isn't set, please create a header with a payload";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: note that protobuf messages aren't self terminating; frankly I'm surprised that even works, but even if it did: you're basically re-implementing serialization inside the serializer; it would seem preferable to actually use the serializer for *what it does*, no?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I edit the answer, is that right now ?

Comment: that indeed looks more like how I might typically use it; ultimately, though, anything that works ... it is up to you!